php7.4-fpm crash or not
I moved from Apache2 to PHP 7.4 FPM + Nginx, it became much better in terms of performance, but the old problem remained, the server can work fine all week, or 2-3 days. But at some point it crashes. Judging by the logs, this is the moment when PHP FPM, namely pm.max_children, reaches its maximum, and until I do the systemctl restart php7.4-fpm, nothing will work. The server runs on a virtual machine with 10 processor cores and 10 gigabytes of RAM, Intel Ice Lake Computed Optimized, in htop everything is more or less good, but at times there is a heavy load and the php fpm cannot cope... What should I do? Just increase the pm.max_children, I tried children, it doesn’t really help. I started with 24, reached 200-300 and the server began to crash much less frequently, but the problem remains. I’m thinking, maybe I should somehow configure the reboot of php fpm when pm.max_children >= 200 appears? Is it possible to do this?
[20-Jun-2024 10:07:56] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 37 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:07:57] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 45 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:07:58] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 55 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:07:59] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 65 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:00] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 75 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:01] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 85 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:02] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 95 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:03] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 105 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:04] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 115 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:05] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 125 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:06] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 5 idle, and 135 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:07] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 8 idle, and 140 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:08] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 7 idle, and 142 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:13] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 152 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:14] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 160 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:15] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 170 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:23] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 187 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:24] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 195 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:25] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 205 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:26] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 215 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:27] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 225 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:28] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 235 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:29] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 245 total children
[20-Jun-2024 10:08:30] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (250), consider raising it

my settings php-fpm
/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf:
emergency_restart_threshold = 2
emergency_restart_interval = 6
process_control_timeout = 2s
include=/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
/pool.d/www.conf:
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.max_requests = 500
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 1024M // I know that this is a lot, but my site is very old and large, there are a lot of scripts that are heavy, without this setting it gives a 500 error
